# TYPO3 dropdown items from DB

Tags: typo3

I need to have a dropdown list with items from DB on frontend.

```
    {namespace femanager=In2code\Femanager\ViewHelpers}
<f:render section="default" arguments="{_all}" />
<f:section name="default">
    <div class="femanager_fieldset femanager_origin control-group">
        <label for="femanager_field_origin" class="control-label">
            <f:translate key="tx_femanager_domain_model_user.origin" />
            <f:if condition="{femanager:Validation.IsRequiredField(fieldName:'origin')}">
                <span>*</span>
            </f:if>
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <femanager:form.select
                    id="femanager_field_origin"
                    property="origin"
                    options="{femanager:Form.GetCountries()}"
                    defaultOption="{f:translate(key:'pleaseChoose')}"
                    class="input-block-level"
                    additionalAttributes="{femanager:Validation.FormValidationData(settings:settings,fieldName:'origin')}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

it's code of my input and it show countries but I need get items from DB table.

Tell me please how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use form.select viewhelper from fluid and use your model.

**Template**

```
<f:form.select name="countries"
    options="{countries}" optionValueField="uid" optionLabelField="name"
    sortByOptionLabel="name"
    prependOptionLabel="Select one ..."
    prependOptionValue="0"/>
```

**Assign your model in Controller**

```
public function yourAction() {
    $countries = $this->countryRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('countries', $countries);
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Tell me please, where is placed this controller ? I just only begin to learning TYPO3

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how it work. I added dropdown field in fronted to page profile (I use my own extension). The field name is origin. Also I have controller in typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Classes/Controller/OriginController.php.  I try to edit this controller but nothing happening. I think that this controller not using. Tell me please, which controller I should edit to send origin data to my field on page profile. (also I use femanager extension)

Comment: Clarify your problem. Did you have own extension or a extension that extend femanager? From which database table and field should your data come from. Be more specific in your question.

Comment: It is my own extension. It must extend femanager extension. What done for now:
- Extended feruser on backend
- added custom dropdown select field named "origin"
- added possible to change dropdown list (adding, deleting items)

Now it need to show this select field on frontend profile page with those fields which I added in backend.

Comment: Information can be found: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/BestPractice/Index.html#newfields and example extension https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanagerextended

Comment: Thank  you I seen it( But it can't help me. There is nothing about dropdown lists and how to get items from db (